# Unknown command CLUSTER Error with Redis cluster in Spring Boot 1.3.4.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data

I have a redis cluster with master, slave and 3 sentinel servers. The master and slave is map to dns names as node1-redis-dev.com, node2-redis-dev.com. The redis server version is 2.8

I include below in my application.properties file.

```
spring.redis.cluster.nodes=node1-redis-dev.com:6379,node2-redis-dev.com:6379
spring.redis.pool.max-idle=8
spring.redis.pool.min-idle=0
spring.redis.pool.max-active=-1
spring.redis.pool.max-wait=-1
```

Also I use below code because only with above property I get apache.commons.pool2.impl.BaseGenericObjectPool exception. So I add below code as mentioned in [spring data](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#_enabling_redis_cluster) link.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    /**
     * Type safe representation of application.properties
     */
    @Autowired ClusterConfigurationProperties clusterProperties;

    public @Bean RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {

        return new JedisConnectionFactory(
            new RedisClusterConfiguration(clusterProperties.getNodes()));
    }
}
```

I have below in my pom,

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I got below error while application start,

> Error creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/RedisAutoConfiguration$RedisConnectionConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR unknown command
>   'CLUSTER'

Comment: Redis Cluster is supported since Redis 3.0.

Comment: @mp911de Any reference link for it please

Comment: https://redis.io/download

Comment: @mp911de Thanks for the info. I guess according to my set up i should use RedisSentinelConfiguration instead of RedisClusterConfiguration know.